# Adding education level tags?

Tags: discussion

In browsing the site today I noticed a number of questions where the first comment was "what level of education" (or similar).

We should add tags to help answer that question and further categorize the question. We'd have to come up with something that was culture agnostic (E.g. US folks may not know what KS2 is in UK). Perhaps age groups? E.g. 5-10, 10-14, etc.?