# Questions to collect interdisciplinary content?

Tags: discussion

Are these sort of questions useful? If so, what should be a couple of ways we pilot them to gauge what should be tweaked in the wording or age-domain boundaries? Are labels and a different type of question better for collecting and curating this type of knowledge from teachers implementing and creating various curricula?

Related to:
[Adding education level tags?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/adding-education-level-tags)

Examples I posted to test the waters:

- [CS connections to Life Sciences for ages 11-14?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/cs-connections-to-life-sciences-for-ages-11-14)
- [CS connections to Life Science for ages 14-18?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/cs-connections-to-life-science-for-ages-14-18)

Comment: A discussion as begun [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61369/discussion-on-question-by-bennett-brown-cs-connections-to-life-sciences-for-ages).

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with interdisciplinary questions; in fact, I rather like them. However, I'm not too much of a fan of near-identical questions that just change the age range, unless there's a **specific reason to separate the age ranges**.

A more specific topic to link with a different discipline (e.g. modelling cell growth with computing) would probably solve this problem—instead of asking for a list of ideas and picking the ones you want out of the 'big list', try to ask about solving a specific problem you've encountered. Presumably, the curriculum for 11- to 14-year-olds will then dictate the sort of topics you could link to CS, giving you better questions that are less similar.

What I think would work well:

> **Title**: How can I connect the topic of cell growth to CS lessons for ages 16-17?
>
> **Body**: [include specific details about what the students know about the topic, and their CS proficiency; explain the problem you're having so far]

I can't really see how your current questions would involve *substantially* different answers, so it might be wise to either edit those, or consider asking for them to be merged.

Comment: Exactly so! The type of question is fine, but should be really specific. "What are ways to tie computer science into a unit on population growth and population pressures?"